# How to efficiently sort list of nodes with next and previous node references?

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, language-agnostic

I have a collection of items in *random* each having the following data structures:

```
// NOTE: Was "Vertex" in the comments...
public class Item
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

public class Node
{
    public Item Next { get; set; }
    public Item Previous { get; set; }
}
```

Example:

```
var a = new Item();
var b = new Item();
var c = new Item();
var d = new Item();

var nodeA = new Node() { Previous = null };
var nodeB = new Node() { Previous = a };
nodeA.Next = b;
var nodeC = new Node() { Previous = b };
nodeB.Next = c;
var nodeD = new Node() { Previous = c, Next = null };
nodeC.Next = d;

// This would be input to the sort method (completely random order).
var items = new []{ nodeC, nodeA, nodeD, nodeB };

// Execute sort

// Result: nodeA, nodeB, nodeC, nodeD.
```

Obviously a O(n<sup>2</sup>) solution is possible. However, I would like to sort these in the correct order in less than O(n<sup>2</sup>). Is this possible?

Comment: You mean sorting a doubly-linked list.

Comment: I imagine some hacked form of a quicksort could potentially yield results of less than O(n2)

Comment: @SLaks - Sort of - yes. However, there is no definition of start/end nodes of the doubly-linked list. The "first" could actually be in the middle.

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky, in that case you have a circular list? This can, by definition, never be sorted (unless it has no or all equal items in it). However, if you define a sentinel node, then you effectively define a start and end for your linked list.

Comment: Ummm.... I think one normally interprets the node with previous=null to be the first.

Comment: @SLacks - Sorry I realized that I incorrectly translated the code to the question wrong. Each `Node` doesn't have a reference to the next `Node`, it has a reference to the Vertex... or the next 'item'.

Comment: Everyone - sorry I translated the code wrong, this *isn't* a doubly-linked list... slightly different. I was translating the code over to the question to simplify and didn't include an important class difference.

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky, so what is your sort key? If it is `Vertex`, which of the two? Because if you have the vertices (a, b) in node 1 and  (b, a) in node 2 the "list" cannot be sorted. What are the guarantees on the vertices in the nodes?

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky: Why would you make things so much harder for yourself? Unless this implementation was determined by someone else, in which case I have to say that I feel sorry for you having to deal with code written by someone who doesn't understand the concept of linked lists.

Comment: @JAB - It was written by me and I completely understand the concept of linked lists. The problem is that these classes are two completely unrelated items and can't be grouped into a linked list. Without going into detail about my domain for the problem, you have to blindly accept this, or don't read this question.

Comment: Seriously? Why was this down voted?

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky: Well, that aside, you might want to re-edit your code snippet. You're still assigning to the `Next` attribute of `Item` objects despite them having no `Next`. Hm... just how different is the actual implementation from the one you show such that you can't simply have individual `Node`s be wrappers for each `Item` with links to the next and previous `Node`s?

Comment: @Lucero - The domain guarantees that the case you gave will not occur. It is guaranteed that an order exists.

Comment: @JAB - Yup, didn't catch that when I made the fix, thanks.

Comment: @JAB - Because the `Node`s are built in such a way that they are unaware of other `Node`s. Explaining the domain of the problem is too long for comments.

Comment: Regardless, if you're determined to keep this implementation it might be a good idea to use something other than "Next" and "Previous" when referencing `Item`s from `Node`s. Other people might get confused about whether they're in linked lists or not if you plan on letting others work with the source code later. Also, sorry if I've seemed rude; it's just disappointing to come up with an elegant solution and then find out that the solution doesn't work because the requirements changed. I'm sure you've had similar experiences.

Comment: @JAB - In the actual code, they're not `Next`/`Previous`, they're `NextContent` and `PreviousContent`, which makes perfect sense when you see the big picture.

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky, so assuming we have a comparer for two nodes (let's call them `x` and `y`) your guarantee is that `(x.Next > y.Prev) == (x.Prev < y.Next)`, for every combination of `x` and `y`?

Comment: Either I'm missing something, or this question makes no sense at all. What key are you trying to sort on? Do you want a list of nodes in order by previous or next item? Or do you want to put the list of items in some kind of order? Sorting the array of nodes is trivial: just supply a comparison delegate to `Array.Sort`. I don't see how the data structure you've presented here is worthwhile for anything but confusing yourself.

Comment: @Lucero - Here's the problem - you can't directly compare two **Vertexes** (items) therefore the `x.Next > y.Prev` is moot. Everything has to be compared via the `Node`.

Comment: @JAB - No worries. I didn't properly translate the code and therefore made myself look like I didn't realize it was a doubly linked-list. Everyone starts saying "Well obviously you don't know that!" when it was my fault I didn't translate a proper sample for SO. I'm legally not allowed to post the code I'm working with, which is why I had to translate (albeit poorly...). I'm thinking I might delete this question and re-ask but with the correct code...

Comment: @Jim - I'm not confusing myself. I understand the problem just fine especially with the understanding of the domain and scope of the problem. To answer your question yes: the sort order should be by previous/next item.

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky: I'm not sure you'd be able to get better than O(n^2) time with the implementation as provided, anyway, considering how you'd have to do the comparisons, but if you feel that would be for the best, then go right ahead. ...Actually, I suddenly have an idea for how this might be done. Going to edit my original answer.

Comment: It's good that you understand the problem. Unfortunately, your explanation and the code that you supplied are insufficient to pass that understanding on to us. Your idea of posting a new question with correct code is a good one.

Comment: @JAB - Which is the problem that I've run into. A O(n<sup>2</sup>) solution is easy, but me an my colleagues have been trying to optimize this and haven't found an easy way to do so.

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky: Well, look at my answer for a new possibility.

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky, **[vertices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex)** is a correct plural form of vertex. If we abstract your problem a bit, I think you should be able to get an almost linear sort time. If we have a dictionary where we store the two nodes associated with each content item (the content hash could be used as dictionary key for instance), then you can basically use it as linked list (jumping from node to content to node to content etc.) and therefore return them in an ordered fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at it... assuming you aren't using circular lists, couldn't you just iterate through your random-order array until you find the starting node (the one with `.Previous == null`) and then return the node? I mean, one of the advantages of a linked list is that you don't have to store references to all the nodes in a separate data structure, just have them each connected to each other. (Well, depending on how the language implementation you're using does reference counting and garbage collection, if it does them at all.)

But basically, unless you have an immediate need after the operation to access an element a certain distance from the starting node, I'd recommend just immediately returning the starting node when encountered and then lazily assigning to an array of the proper size as you use each successive node. In fact, even if you create a new array and assign to it, wouldn't the worst-time case still just be O(n), with n being the number of nodes? O(n) to find the starting node, and then another O(n) n to iterate through the list, assigning each node to the corresponding index in an array of the same size as your input array.

---

Based on your updated question, it might be a good idea for you to implement a temporary set of linked lists. As you initially iterate through the list, you'd check the `Next` and `Previous` elements of each node, and then store the `Next`s and `Previous`es in Dictionary-esque objects (I'm not sure what .NET object would be best suited for that) as keys, with linked-list nodes wrapped around the existing `Node`s referencing the `Item`s being the values. That way you'd build up the links as you go along without any actual sorting, and would ultimately just iterate through your temporary list, assigning the `Node`s wrapped by the listnodes to a new array to return.

This should be better than O(n^2) due to dictionary accesses generally being constant-time on average (though worst-case asymptotic behavior is still O(n)), I believe.

Comment: See the updated OP... I forgot to include an important detail that *doesn't* make this a doubly-linked list.

Comment: Good point. This problem reduces to a simpler one in linear time: convert the linked list into an array, then sort the array, then convert the array into a doubly-linked list. So you can clearly do as good with this (asymptotically speaking) as with an array containing the same data... O(n log n) in most cases, but O(n) in some very conspicuous ones.

Comment: @JAB - Yeah this is what I've been experimenting with for the past hour or so. I'll update and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky: Okay, hope it goes well.

Answer (score 0):

[Merge Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) comes to mind... I think this should be applicable here and it performs (worst case) in O(n log n).

> Merge sort is often the best choice for sorting a linked list: in this
>   situation it is relatively easy to implement a merge sort in such a
>   way that it requires only Θ(1) extra space, and the slow random-access
>   performance of a linked list makes some other algorithms (such as
>   quicksort) perform poorly, and others (such as heapsort) completely
>   impossible.

**Edit:** after re-reading your question, it doesn't make much sense anymore. Basically you want to sort so that the items are in the order given by the list? That is doable in linear O(n) time: first you travel backwards to the first item in the list (via references) and then you just yield each item forward. Or are your `Next`/`Previous` not references?

Comment: I've updated my OP that explains that provides some detail I forgot to include. If you're at the base divide-and-conquer case, how do you know to swap the items?

Comment: Yeah, so the catch is that the `Next/Previous` aren't references to the next `Node` but the next `Item` (I renamed from Vertex..).

Answer (score 0):

I think merge sort can work. Something like...

```
  merge_sort_list(list, chain_length)
  1. if chain_length > 1 then
  2.    merge_sort_list(list, chain_length/2)
  3.    middle_node = step_into_by(list, chain_length)
  4.    merge_sort_list(middle, chain_length - chain_length/2)
  5.    merge_list_halves(list, middle, chain_length)

  merge_list_halves(list, middle, chain_length)
  1. ... you get the idea
```

Comment: See the updated OP... I forgot to include an important detail that doesn't make this a doubly-linked list.